# C++ Printing strange characters

Tags: c++

So I have this program below and currently after I run it outputs this:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
eklpyqrbgjdwtcaxzsnifvhmou
TEst
iyniЉhb�{���{���`�5b�v4b�q4b�{����8b�`�5b��`{���{����o���7�vb��{�����or��o���@`�lhb���5b��`x@
```

any reason why? 
also the lines which are meant to be randomised currently aren't random

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    char Text[256];
    array<char, 26> letters;
    iota(letters.begin(), letters.end(), 'a');
    for(char c: letters) //Array before shuffling
    {   
        cout << c;
    }
    cout << '\n';
    random_shuffle(letters.begin(), letters.end());
    for(char c: letters) //After shuffling
    {
        cout << c;
    }
    cout << '\n';
    cin.getline (Text,256);
    for (char & c : Text)
    {
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'A')
        {
            cout << letters[0];
        }
        else if (c == 'b' || c == 'B')
        {
             cout << letters[1];
        }
        else if (c == 'c' || c == 'C')
        {
             cout << letters[2];
        }
        else if (c == 'd' || c == 'D')
        {
             cout << letters[3];
        }
        else if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
        {
             cout << letters[4];
        }
        else if (c == 'f' || c == 'F')
        {
             cout << letters[5];
        }
        else if (c == 'g' || c == 'G')
        {
             cout << letters[6];
        }
        else if (c == 'h' || c == 'H')
        {
             cout << letters[7];
        }
        else if (c == 'i' || c == 'I')
        {
             cout << letters[8];
        }
        else if (c == 'j' || c == 'J')
        {
             cout << letters[9];
        }
        else if (c == 'k' || c == 'K')
        {
             cout << letters[10];
        }
        else if (c == 'l' || c == 'L')
        {
             cout << letters[11];
        }
        else if (c == 'm' || c == 'M')
        {
             cout << letters[12];
        }
        else if (c == 'n' || c == 'N')
        {
            cout << letters[13];
        }
        else if (c == 'o' || c == 'O')
        {
            cout << letters[14];
        }
        else if (c == 'p' || c == 'P')
        {
            cout << letters[15];
        }
        else if (c == 'q' || c == 'Q')
        {
            cout << letters[16];
        }
        else if (c == 'r' || c == 'R')
        {
            cout << letters[17];
        }
        else if (c == 's' || c == 'S')
        {
            cout << letters[18];
        }
        else if (c == 't' || c == 'T')
        {
            cout << letters[19];
        }
        else if (c == 'u' || c == 'U')
        {
            cout << letters[20];
        }
        else if (c == 'v' || c == 'V')
        {
            cout << letters[21];
        }
        else if (c == 'w' || c == 'W')
        {
            cout << letters[22];
        }
        else if (c == 'x' || c == 'X')
        {
            cout << letters[23];
        }
        else if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y')
        {
            cout << letters[24];
        }
        else if (c == 'z' || c == 'Z')
        {
            cout << letters[25];
        }
        else if (c == ' ')
        {
            cout << ' ';
        }       
        else if (c == '/n')
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else 
        {
        cout << c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the power of the ASCII table to remove those `if` statements.

Comment: `else if (c == '/n')` i think it should be `\n`

Comment: Yeah I get /n and \n mixed up  

This is really my first time looking at C++ what are ASCII tables?

Comment: look at tolower and the fact that lowercase char 'a' minus 'a'==0 and lowercase char 'z' minus 'a'==25

Comment: @MarounMaroun Use `std::tolower` to remove those `if` statements.

Comment: @ColdCat That may be the case on your machine, but I've worked on systems where it wasn't.

Comment: @JamesKanze I Agree it didn't work on EBCDIC systems (mostly AS/400 OS/390...) but as source use brackets and braces I made the assumption that the system is ASCII compatible.

Comment: @ColdCat All C and C++ sources will use brackets and braces (which are present in EBCDIC, although not in international ASCII).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else if (c == '/n')
{
    return 0;
}
```

Should be

```
else if (c == '\n')
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, if you're looking for the end of your input, you actually want

```
else if (c == '\0')
{
    return 0;
}
```

Which is a null terminator which indicates the end of a string. Basically you're getting all the junk that is stored in the entire 256 character array.

However, that doesn't help with your 29 `if` `else` statements. Try this:

```
if(c == ' '){ // Space
    cout << ' ';
}
else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){ // Uppercase
    cout << letters[c - 'A'];
}
else if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){ // Lowercase
    cout << letters[c - 'a'];
}
else if(c == '\0'){ // End of string
    return 0;
}
else{ // Anything else
    cout << c;
}
```

### How it works:

There are not "letters" in a computer, only binary. 'A' doesn't exist, but `01000001` which is `65` which is `A` does. So if you enter an 'A', your program will see a 65. However, I just happen to know that in your `letters` array, you have an A in position `0`, so `letters[0] == letters['A' - 'A']`. The same logic can be used for B, C, D, ect. The same thing for the lowercase letters, they just at a different range (97-122).

Comment: @SteamPunk_Devil if this has solved your problem, please upvote and accept.

Comment: why `c - 'A'` or `c - 'a'`? Suppose `c='A'` then u r printing `'A'-'A'` i.e 0. why?

Comment: Concerning the coding: that's probably the case on his machine, but it's certainly not guaranteed, or even universal.  The letters aren't guaranteed to be contiguous in the encoding (and aren't in some widespread encodings).

Comment: ASCII is a VERY widespread encoding. As in, every PC/Mac/Linux computer uses ASCII to the best of my knowledge. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to transfer a simple text file from one computer to the next without it looking different on each one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
else if (c == '/n')   // '/n' is not correct
```

change it to

```
else if (c == '\0')   // Check EOF
```

Comment: Compare against `'\n'` won't help, because [`cin.getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) doesn't store delimiter (new line) character. Correct way is to compare with `'\0'`